Power BI - Calculate year-to-current date over multiple prior years
Say today is 5/22, I want to dynamically calculate the YTD sale of the last five years.
2024: sales from 1/1/24-5/22/24
2023: sales from 1/1/23-5/22/23
2022: sales from 1/1/22-5/22/22
and so on.
I have tried multiple DAX formulas but I could only get the sales of entire the month of May from previous year but I only want to sum them to the current date.
Thanks in advance!

do you need 5 separate value for last 5 years? or need 1 final value of SUM of 5 years?

5 different values

I have added 2 measure in the answer. You can create rest three following the same logic. hope it will work.

maybe you can try to create a flag column in date table.
flag =
IF (
    YEAR ( TODAY () ) - YEAR ( 'Date'[Date] ) < 5
        && MONTH ( 'Date'[Date] ) <= MONTH ( TODAY () )
        && DAY ( 'Date'[Date] ) <= DAY ( TODAY () ),
    "y"
)

then all the date that you need will be marked as 'y'

you can create measures as below-
YearSumOne =

var endDateYearOne = today()
var startDateYearOne = startofyear(endDateYearOne)

return 
calculate(
    sum(yourTableName(salesColumnName)),
    filter(
        all(yourTableName),
        and(
            yourTableName(Date) >= startDateYearOne,
            yourTableName(Date) <= endDateYearOne
        )
    )
)

YearSumTwo =

var endDateYearTwo = dateadd(today(),-1,year)
var startDateYearTwo = startofyear(endDateYearTwo)

return 
calculate(
    sum(yourTableName(salesColumnName)),
    filter(
        all(yourTableName),
        and(
            yourTableName(Date) >= startDateYearTwo,
            yourTableName(Date) <= endDateYearTwo
        )
    )
)

You can now create rest Three measure following the above logic.

You need only start date so using datesbetween can be used.
YTD Sales = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Sales'[SalesAmount]), 
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Date'[Date], 
        DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1), 
        TODAY()
    )
)

